# Why do we take $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ for a parametric circle when we can take the opposite?

Tags: calculus

Both $x = \cos t$, $y = \sin t$ and $x = \sin t$, $y = \cos t$ describe a circle

So why is the first parameterization so commonly used in mathematics, and not the second?

Comment: Because it is the most natural, from a geometric point of view.

Comment: @Bernard I'm sure the OP would be very grateful if you could provide more details about what makes it more natural geometrically.

Comment: A related question would be: why is $\sin$ called $\sin$ and $\cos$ called $\cos$ and not the reverse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because we usually
start the circle
at the right.
There,
the coordinates are
$(1, 0)$,
which is
$(\cos(0), \sin(0))$.

If we started it at the top,
we would probably use
$(\sin(t), \cos(t))$.

Comment: But why do we usually start the circle at the right?  Does that have any natural motivation?  (if asked to draw a circle, I would likely start near the top).

Comment: Tradition. For a somewhat relevant discussion, look up how Knuth discusses the various ways of drawing trees in TAOCP.

Comment: Are you saying that the tradition predates the parametrization of the circle by cosine and sine?  I find that interesting and somewhat surprising!

Comment: I don't know. (See - I can answer any question.)

Answer (score 5):

Because $e^{it} = \cos t+i\sin t$ (but not **only** because of that).

Answer (score 3):

Because of convension.

It is customary to view angles as lying with the vertex at the origin and the right leg along the positive $x$-axis. That means that small angles will have their left leg in the first quadrant, and right angles will have the left leg along the positive $y$-axis. Because of this, the cosine of the angle happens to be the $x$-coordinate of the point on the left leg that is distance $1$ from the vertex, while the sine of the angle is the $y$-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is reasonable to view tan $\theta$ as more "natural" than cot $\theta$, then one advantage to making $x$ the cosine coordinate is it gives a direct correspondence between slopes and tangents.  But I much prefer the motivation in Michael Hardy's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using $t$ is the most ‘natural’  parametrisation  because $t$ is the `polar angle`  of the point $(x,y)$ in a standard polar coordinates system.